# Scanner Input validation on a single entry line from user

Tags: java

I have a user enter a string of integers and I add them to an ArrayList, however I need to validate each entry is a positive integer. I have tried do/while loops, nested while loops, while with nested if and each runs into its own set of problems.

As an example of my current setup:
User enters for example: 1 2 3 4
pageVar is my Scanner and pageRef is my ArrayList

```
System.out.println("Please enter the page reference string: ");
        while(pageVar.hasNext()) {
            if (pageVar.hasNextInt() && pageVar.nextInt() > 0) {
                pageRef.add(pageVar.nextInt());
            }
            else if (pageVar.nextInt() < 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter valid page reference string: ");
            }
            else if (!pageVar.hasNext()) {
                pageVar.close();
            }
        }
```

running this my while gets stuck waiting for more input and I cannot determine how to break it.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `nextInt()` you consume a value. **Store** the value before you compare.

```
while (pageVar.hasNextInt()) {
    int v = pageVar.nextInt();
    if (v > 0) {
        pageRef.add(v);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%d: is not a valid reference value.%n", v);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have input your suggestion, however I am still stuck inside the while loop. I have a print statement outside the loop to print the array, however it is not reaching the statement.
```
while (pageVar.hasNextInt()) {
      int v = pageVar.nextInt();
      if (v > 0) {
          pageRef.add(v);
          System.out.println(pageRef);
      } else {
          System.out.printf("%d: is not a valid reference value.%n", v);
      }
  }
  
  System.out.println("here"); //this line is not reached
```

Comment: Input something not an `int` to end the loop. Alternatively, close the stream. ctrl-z on windows, ctrl-d on every other platform.

Answer (score 0):

//you could try validating the int as it is being entered with a for loop??
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int[] numbers = new int[4];
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
        numbers[i] = kbd.nextInt();
        
        while(numbers[i] < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");
            numbers[i] = kbd.nextInt();
        }
    }
            
}
```

}